# Aptana Studio rails using old Ruby , Rials Version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, aptana3

I downloaded aptana Studio 3 for ubuntu 14.4 recently. When I create a rails application it seems to run on old version of ruby and rails.
In the linux terminal when ask for version of rails and ruby I get new versions like 4.2.0 and 2.2.1.
But in aptana in the terminal it provides i get older version of both ruby(1.9) and rails(2.x)
How to make aptana point to a new version

Comment: Did this solution work ?

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a `.rvmrc` for that project in its root directory, so that your IDE would load proper ruby and rails version.

For Example create a simple `.rvmrc` file in your root directory

place the following content into your .rvmrc file

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p484@gemset --create
```

By this way, you say your IDE to load appropriate ruby versions and gemset specified.

It works like charm,

Comment: Can you give me a more hints on how to create this?